# What does 狗吃连帮 mean?

Tags: phrase, idioms

I heard people say this phrase once or twice, in derogatory tone. It sounds like 狗吃连帮 or 狗吃粮帮. Internet search gives no result, but it didn't sound like some local dialect to me.

I heard people say things like 他们这些人就是狗吃连帮 or　我们得提防着他们点狗吃连帮．Something like these．

@Semaphore,@NS.X.,I heard both people from Tianjin and Shandong say it. Maybe it's a saying that goes in Huabei area, like sayings like 不招人待见 go only in some parts of northern China (but which is now more generally known). I asked those people what they meant by this 狗吃连帮. One says it means 一帮人勾结起来做坏事, but he's not sure how to write "lian bang". Another says it means 一撮人私底下谋划陷害别人, written as 狗吃连邦. But she's not sure how to interpret 连邦 literally, preferring to view it as a slang that's oral in nature.

Comment: Are you able to supply the sentence or more context that this phrase is used in?

Comment: I heard people say things like 他们这些人就是狗吃连帮 or　我们得提防着他们点狗吃连帮．Something like these．

Comment: do you mean 狗急跳墙？ which means "even a worm will turn"

Comment: @CaffHuang: No. Everyone knows 狗急跳墙 :)

Comment: Maybe it's something like:
狗吃良心

Comment: @Eric possibly 狗肺狼心? Whats your local dialect?

Comment: Dialect matters a lot here. Please tell us what dialect this is in, or which part of China/Chinese speaking region did you hear this.

Comment: 狗吃 some kind of 棒?

Comment: Sorry never heard of that as a native speaker, I feel it means something like 吃里扒外

Comment: As a native Chinese speaker I have never heard such expression. It may be some sort of local language, and local language is diversified to an astonishing extent!

Comment: I never heard of it. I searched baidu, found only two entries from the same grafiti like post.

Comment: Actually 连邦 means "alliance". That's the same to 连帮.

Comment: I am a Chinese, I never heard it too.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's origin is 勾持连帮，maybe it's a local phrase that only be used in a small  district.
勾持 may means 勾搭，and be sounded to 狗, 连帮 means to be a group, that's why it's means 勾结起来做坏事. 
Realy never heard of this word.